# Throwing custom exception and problems with {} in java with eclipse

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, extends

I'm trying to create custom exceptions for my application.  It generates a random number, takes a character from BufferedReader, associates the character with an int through an enum, and outputs whether or not the int is higher, lower, or equals to the random int.  Then you can play again.

I have three errors.  In both of my custom exception classes I get a delete token '{',{ error on the class body {.  Then for my BufferedReader  the .readline() method throws an IOException.  So I my custom exception NewIOException extends IOException and adds a try, catch, and finally block to catch it.  I get the error "Unhandled Exception type IOException" even though my custom exception extends IOException.  What am I doing wrong?  I've looked around, I don't see anything to take care of this.  Nothing on custom exceptions extending IOException and the custom exception I've read is short and not helpful.  I have a book "Learn Java for Android Development", but the code examples don't really cover it.

Here's my code.

```
package randomInt;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.Character;

public class Guess{
    int getNewRandom(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(25);
        return num;
    }
    public void userInput() throws StringLengthException, NewIOException'{
        System.out.println("Guess a letter between a and z: ");
        int intRandom = getNewRandom();
        try{
            BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`
            String string= cin.readLine();      
            //StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string);
            int length = string.length();
            if(length > 1){
                throw new StringLengthException();
            }
            //String[] stringToToken = new String[numTokens];
            char guess = string.charAt(0);      
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(guess);
            //GuessDeterminer determine = new GuessDeterminer(ch);
            int x = GuessDeterminer.determineGuess(ch);
            if(x > intRandom){
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high.");
                System.out.println("Choose again: ");
                userInput();
            }
            else if(x < intRandom){
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
                System.out.println("Choose again: ");
                userInput();
            }
            else if(x == intRandom){
                System.out.println("Your correct, congratulations!");
                System.out.println("Play again!");
                System.out.println("Guess a letter between a and z: ");
                getNewRandom();
                userInput();
            }
        }
        catch (NewIOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Guess a letter between a and z: ");
            getNewRandom();
            userInput();
        }       
    }
}


package randomInt;

public class StringLengthException extends Exception{
    super("A new letter of length one from a - z must be chosen.");
    super("Choose a letter: ");
    Guess.userInput();
}


package randomInt;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NewIOException extends IOException{
    super("Input Error");
    System.out.println("Input new letter from a - z: ");
    Guess.userInput();
}


package randomInt;

public enum GuessDeterminer {
    a('a'),
    b('b'),
    c('c'),
    d('c'),
    e('c'),
    f('c'),
    g('c'),
    h('c'),
    i('c'),
    j('c'), 
    k('c'),
    l('c'),
    m('c'),
    n('c'),
    o('c'),
    p('c'),
    q('c'),
    r('c'),
    s('c'),
    t('c'),
    u('c'),
    v('c'),
    w('c'),
    x('c'),
    y('c'),
    z('c');
    private final char character;
    public final int returnAnswer;
    GuessDeterminer(char character){
        this.character = character;
        this.returnAnswer = determineGuess(character);      
    }
    static int determineGuess(char ch){
        int x = 0;
        switch(ch){ 
        case 'a'    :   x = 0;
        case 'b'    :   x = 1;
        case 'c'    :   x = 2;
        case 'd'    :   x = 3;
        case 'e'    :   x = 4;
        case 'f'    :   x = 5;
        case 'g'    :   x = 6;
        case 'h'    :   x = 7;
        case 'i'    :   x = 8;
        case 'j'    :   x = 9;
        case 'k'    :   x = 10;
        case 'l'    :   x = 11;
        case 'm'    :   x = 12;
        case 'n'    :   x = 13;
        case 'o'    :   x = 14;
        case 'p'    :   x = 15;
        case 'q'    :   x = 16;
        case 'r'    :   x = 17;
        case 's'    :   x = 18;
        case 't'    :   x = 19;
        case 'u'    :   x = 20;
        case 'v'    :   x = 21;
        case 'w'    :   x = 22;
        case 'x'    :   x = 23;
        case 'y'    :   x = 24;
        case 'z'    :   x = 25;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

These are my edits to the exception classes.  My call to Guess.userInput() needed to throw StringLengthException in both exception classes, I don't know if that was the right move. I also have errors on extends in my exception classes, the comma in my throws clause for Guess.java, and immediately below that the println statement. The nature of those errors is explained in the comments below.

```
public class StringLengthException extends Exception throws StringLenthException{
    public StringLengthException(){
        super("StringLengthException thrown.");
        System.out.println("A new letter of length one from a - z must be chosen.");
        System.out.println("Choose a letter: ");
        Guess.userInput();
    }
}

public class NewIOException extends IOException throws StringLengthException{
    public NewIOException(){
        super("Input Error");
        System.out.println("Input new letter from a - z: ");
        Guess.userInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to have an apostrophe in your `throws` declaration.

Comment: Alright that seems to take care of my problem, along with getting rid of NewIOException and just using IOException.  Why can't I extend IOException from NewIOException and have that cover IOException though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code  :

```
super("Input Error");
System.out.println("Input new letter from a - z: ");
Guess.userInput();
```

Should be in the constructor :

```
public class NewIOException extends IOException{
    public NewIOException () {
        super("Input Error");
        // though it's a bad practice to
        // have this logic in the exception class
        System.out.println("Input new letter from a - z: ");
        Guess.userInput(); 
    }
}
```

You have the same error in your other exception class - `StringLengthException`.

However, even if you fix the compilation errors, an exception should not contain code to handle the exception. That's what catch blocks are for.

Another problem in your code - when you have a `catch (NewIOException e)`, that clause doesn't catch `IOException`s which are not `NewIOException`. Therefore you should have a `catch (IOException e)` clause. Actually, I don't see where you throw a `NewIOException`, so you should only catch `IOException`.

Your catch blocks can look like this :

```
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also note that if you catch an exception `X`, you don't need a `throws X` clause in your method signature. You either catch the exception or declare that your method `throws` it.

Another error I noticed :

Remove the `throws` clause from your exception classes. This clause is only used in methods.

Comment: I did what you recommended. It was a good answer.  However, I've added more problems. At the comma separating the exception on the userInput declaration in Guess.java I have this error: Multiple markers at this line - Invalid character constant - Syntax error on token ",", @. Then on the next line at println I have this error: Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator  Expression" to complete Expression - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration.

Comment: Then in both exception classes on the extends keyword I have this error: Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token - The serializable class StringLengthException does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long - Syntax error on token "extends", delete this token - Syntax error, insert "ClassBody" to complete ClassDeclaration - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block.  I'm also adding edits to the OP.

Comment: Why can't I extend new IOException to with NewIOException to catch the exception? I created a catch block for StringLengthException and both catch blocks handle the code I put in the exception class, which I deleted.  I still have the same errors in the above comments.

Comment: @Spitz You can extend IOException with NewIOException, but when you `catch NewIOException` it will only catch exceptions of type `NewIOException` or sub-classes of `NewIOException`. If you call a method that throws IOException, you must have a `catch IOException` clause to catch it.